# Is the rate limit quota in Google Plus Pages API for user or for page?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, quota

If suppose i am having more than one google plus pages and configuring them in difference brands (using the same application).In this case the rate limit (say 500 per min) will be decreased for both pages or each page having 500 requests? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rate limit is normally per page or per user.   However you should contact Google when you were granted access to that beta api they should have given you a contact person.

Comment: Hi @DaImTo In our Quotas page it shows as some X Queries per 100 seconds per user.It means for a user (whatever the page is ) i have to use only that X number of queries right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Several Google quotas.   These quotas are valid for all Google APIs the only difference really is the amount of quota you receive.

> Queries per day    10,000   
>   Queries per 100 seconds per user   500 
>   Queries per 100 seconds    1,000

`Queries per day` is a project wide quota.  Your application identified by the client_id and client secrete you are using can run max 10000 request per day.

`Queries per 100 seconds per user`  this is a speed quota or flood protection really.   Each user who has authenticated your application can make a max X queries per 100 seconds.   in the case above the user can make max 500 request with in 100 seconds.

`Queries per 100 seconds` this last one is project wide.  Your application identified by the client_id and client secret. Can make 1000 requests in 100 seconds.

All but the user based one can probably be increased by clicking on the penile icon in the Google developers console.   Depending upon the API you may have to pay for the increase.  I doubt this is the case with the Google+ pages API.